# Generate code when correct picturebox is clicked

Tags: vb.net

I am making a game to help kids learn the different parts of objects as a part of 9th grade tech class syllabus. There will be a picture of a plane and 6 smaller pictures underneath it.
Only three of the pictures will be components of a plane, the others won't.

Only when the person playing has clicked the three right components will they win the game.

I can't figure out a way to code my program so that all three pictures need to be clicked before my program advances.

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far?  Start by trying to break thisd down into a non-graphics problem.  Think about it from a logic standpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take 7 `picturebox` as you are saying, suppose the main `picturebox` is Picturebox1 and the underneath ones are `Picturebox2`, `Picturebox3`, `Picturebox4`, `Picturebox5`, `Picturebox6`, `Picturebox7`.

**If** correct `PictureBox` are 2, 3, 4, then, write the following code under their click events.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load () Handles Mybase.Load
       Textbox1.Hide
       Textbox1.Text = 0
End Sub

Private Sub Picturebox2_Click () Handles Picturebox2.Click
       Textbox1.Text = Val(Textbox1.text) + 1
End Sub

Private Sub Picturebox3_Click () Handles Picturebox3.Click
       Textbox1.Text = Val(Textbox1.text) + 1
End Sub

Private Sub Picturebox3_Click () Handles Picturebox3.Click
       Textbox1.Text = Val(Textbox1.text) + 1
End Sub

Private Sub Textbox1_TextChanged () Handles Textbox1.TextChanged
       If Val(Textbox1.Text) = 3 then
            'things here you want to do when correct pictures are clicked
       End If
End Sub
```

I hope you will understand!

Comment: Glad to be of help! :)